# Google Chrome Web Store thinks .domain.com cookies

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Chrome Web Store refuses "*://.domain.com/" permission, when I would like to upload to store. But when I would like to delete a .domain.com cookie, browser refuses, because "*://.domain.com/" is not granted.

Since 1 October, 2019 update. Anyone has a solution yet?

Comment: The new behavior is correct and intended, see https://crbug.com/1003394 and the [official announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/-_YZ4d4haUg): "The proper way to set a domain cookie is to use the "domain" attribute, e.g. to set a cookie for all subdomains of mydomain.com, use a "domain" attribute of "mydomain.com" (no leading dot required)."

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the links. This trick solved the problem well.